# (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into colum

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, exception, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC, doing my first training project. Recently I have encountered exception while inserting data into table, seems like I can't find solution:

First I have created table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPC] 
(
    [PCID]   INT           NOT NULL,
    [PCName] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [PCDate] DATETIME      NOT NULL
)
```

then a model with attributes:

```
[Table("tblPC")]
public class PC
{
    [Required]
    public int PCID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-z]{2,2}[0-9]{1,1}$")]
    public string PCName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime PCDate { get; set; }
}
```

and then my context class:

```
public class PC_DB_Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<PC> PCs { get; set; }
}
```

and an action:

```
 public ActionResult Submit(PC obj)
 {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            PC_DB_Context PCContext = new PC_DB_Context();
            PCContext.PCs.Add(obj);
            PCContext.SaveChanges();
            return View("PC", obj);
        }
        else 
        {
            return View("EnterPC", obj);
        }
}
```

I just can't avoid exception:

> SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PCID', table 'MyDB.dbo.tblPC'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

when I set identity flag on `PCID` to true and setup increment all works, but what if I don't want it ...

And here is my cshtml:

```
<body>
    <div> 

        <form action="submit" method="post">
            PC ID: <input name="PCID" type="number" value="@Model.PCID" />  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PCID)<br />
            PC Name: <input name="PCName" type="text" value="@Model.PCName" />   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PCName) <br />
            PC Date: <input name="PCDate" type="datetime" value="@DateTime.Now" /><br />
            <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" /><br />
        </form>
        <br />
        @*@Html.ValidationSummary()*@
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question.  If you want SQL Server to automatically handle the id then auto increment is a good option.  If not, then you could assign a default column value.

Comment: The exception is self explanatory. If you don't want to set `PCID` identity column, then you have to provide its values manually while inserting else you have to set `Allow Null` true for this column.

Comment: ... thanks guys, appreciate your response ... I'm poroviding PCID manually from web form together with Name and Date (date is generated into textbox by Razor). Just wondering why database doesn't allow me to write PCID into table column ...

Comment: I guess data entered in form is not available in Submit method (on click of submit button). did you verify this?

Comment: ... yes. When I debug mode I can see that 'obj' in 'Submit' action's parameter has all three values ...

Comment: ... when I set table columns to null-able I have got exception: OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0) ... I understand that it is concurrency exception but I am the only one who is doing table update ...